# What is the following Unicode string \xe9?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

I wanted to know what is the following Unicode string `\xe9`?

And is there a detailed tutorial that explains this Unicode string?

Comment: I have a file with this character: ï and the error displays \xe9

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The unicode string for `\xe9` is an accented e - `é`

`\xe9` is an encoded string. `u'\xe9'` is a Unicode string that contains the unicode character U+00E9 (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE).

References:
From this <s>[link](http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-objects.htm)</s>. Check this [link](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) also. Adding one more [link](https://www.codetable.net/hex/e9)
Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Is there a list of encoded strings like `\xe9` that I can use? And why is there a slash `\` in the string?

Comment: I still dont understand why there is a slash \ in the string?

Comment: I know this is an old answer but it scores high for google searches on "\xE9" so I feel obliged to point out that there is link rot in the first link.