# Laravel Homestead Error on startup

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Hi everyone i have an issue in my laravel homestead and vagrant. i have set up everything in the correct way by reading the Laravel Homestead Docs and watching around 5 videos and when i start the `vagrant up` command, i have this issue:

OS: Windows 8 64-bit.

Vagrang: 1.7.4.

Virtualbox: 5.0.8.

HomesteadBox: latest.

PS: this problem happen to me 4 times and after formating my pc nothing change, same error msg.

```html
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'file' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/io.rb:32:in `encode': "\xE9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/io.rb:32:in `read_until_block'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:162:in `block in execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:160:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:160:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:22:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:404:in `block in raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:403:in `raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:342:in `block in execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in `retryable'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:337:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_5_0.rb:275:in `read_bridged_interfaces'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:271:in `hostonly_config'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:89:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:82:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:82:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:86:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:160:in `handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:516:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:68:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:16:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:32:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:214:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:191:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:516:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run
```

my `Homestead.yaml` file:

```html
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Apps
      to: /home/vagrant/Apps

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Apps/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: 'APP_ENV'
      value: 'local'
    - key: 'APP_DEBUG'
      value: 'true'

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Comment: Hmm...any strange symbols in your Homestead.yaml file? Try redoing your Homestead.yaml file completely from scratch.

Comment: You may also try VirtualBox 4.3.30. I know I had some problems with 5.0 on Windows last time I tried. But it has been awhile since I've tried though.

Comment: i will past my homestead.yaml file here to check, but i think my homestead.yaml file is good.

Comment: Watch out for tabs in your yaml file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327494/what-is-the-following-unicode-string-xe9 relevant

Comment: Yeah, your Homestead.yaml file checks out as good. Hmm...

Comment: Can you give us the full name of `~/Apps` path? Maybe you've got a special character in the name of your home folder in C:\Users directory.

Comment: @prograhammer this is the folder name of (~/Apps) C:\Users\Bahad Soufiane\Apps

Comment: Use a different path to see if it works. Try like `C:/test` instead of `~/Apps`

Comment: i do change to (C:/Apps) and same error :(

Comment: Change all places of `~` used in your Homestead.yaml file. So that would mean your ssh key as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your Homestead.yaml file is saved in UTF-8 and ensure there are no special characters or tabs used in there. Notepad++ is useful for this.
2. Do you have special characters like `é` in the name of your home folder in your C:\Users directory? Typically this problem will show on systems from user names in non-English. Try installing a new user on your windows PC and name it something very simple like "bahad" (no special characters). Then install vagrant, virtualbox, git-bash, homestead/etc. there.
3. You may try modifying your [vagrant/util/io.rb](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/util/io.rb) file and update line 32 to this: `data << io.readpartial(READ_CHUNK_SIZE).force_encoding(‘UTF-8’)` to force encoding.
4. Try [vagrant debug log](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging.html) to see if you can get any more insight into the problem.

I also have a [Homestead on Windows Gist](https://gist.github.com/prograhammer/9493ee04f30dd74e121b) that uses a slightly older version of vagrant and virtualbox successfully on Windows 8-64 (I'll soon be trying the latest versions and updating the Gist). If you install those versions and still have this problem, then I'd say that narrows it down to some strange character found in a pathname on your system being used by vagrant.

Comment: unfortunately :( i do like you said and nothing new.
i'm going to downgrade VirtualBox  to 4.3.30 and see the result.
thank you very much for your help

Comment: Perhaps add a new user to windows. Call it just "bahad". Then reinstall vagrant/virtualbox, git-bash, and homestead etc. on that user account.

Comment: I curious also if the space in your path's name would be an issue or not as well. Let us know if it works under a user account of "bahad" (no spaces/special chars) http://steve-jansen.github.io/blog/2014/03/13/tips-for-vagrant-on-windows/

Comment: Notice that vagrant (hashicorp) also installs at "C:\" root instead of in "Program files".

Answer (score 0):

Change path of your homestead folder